# Custom Authorization Filter vs Policy in ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am designing a new ASP.Net CORE 2.1 WebAPI and I am trying to figure out the best way to implement an authorization system that will fit our needs.  Our roles and permissions are database driven and can mix and match both role-based and individual resource permissions.  So for a given endpoint, the default access may be role based (say Admin only), but the administrator may also assign individual users access to that endpoint (or the opposite; and revoke access to a specific resource otherwise granted by the role).  As a result, each endpoint authorization requires a DB query to determine valid access to that resource.  It seems to me that a custom authorization filter is needed here, but a lot of MS docs and other resources push Policy-based auth and recommend against "rolling your own."  I don't see how a policy based solution would work here, since it's based on static policy claims.  Can our needs be met with policies or is a custom auth filter the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Policy auth is the way to go. Yes, it might be based on a somewhat "static" policy, i.e. multiple actions/controllers may end up using something like `[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]`, but policies themselves are not static. You can define any number of conditions inside a policy handler. You may also mix and match. So, if say something is only available to a "Foo" role, but you also need object level permissions defined by a "Bar" policy, you may certainly do something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Foo", Policy = "Bar")]`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but wouldn't this imply that I need a policy for every endpoint method if I need the flexiblity to override role-based permissions on a per controller action basis?

Comment: Hey @Bryan Lewis, I'm in a similar situation. Curious to hear, which route did you go down in the end? Any pros or cons found?